# cast stl::vector containing pointers to stl::vector containing constant pointers

Tags: c++, templates, casting, constants

Consider the following class:

```
class SomeInfo
{
private:
    std::vector<someObj *> _myVector;

public:
    const std::vector<const someObj*>& getInfoVector() const
    {
        return _myVector;
    }
};
```

When I try to compile with gcc 4.1.2, it gives me the following error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
‘const std::vector<const someObj*, std::allocator<const someObj*> >&’ 
from expression of type 
‘const std::vector<someObj*, std::allocator<someObj*> >
```

If I remove the 'const' in front of 'someObj *', then it compiles, but I don't want to return vector with non-constant pointers, because I don't want the objects referenced by them to be changed from outside my SomeInfo class. What would you do in this situation?

Comment: Why not just make _myVector a vector of constant pointers in the first place?

Comment: Because on a later stage, there will be a destructor, which will have to 'delete' constant pointers, which I know that is allowed in the language, but I consider it ugly! From my point of view, const is const and should not be touched ... which is not the case with this vector member, it is not const, I just want to give const access to its values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do in this situation is forget about returning a `vector` (or reference thereto). The caller can't make any changes, so doesn't need to see any particular container. Other answers explain why you can't refer to your vector as if it were a vector of `const someObj*`. For that matter, if in future you change your class to use a `deque` instead of a `vector` you can't return a reference to that as if it were a vector either. Since callers just need access to the elements, let's give them that:

```
const someObj *getInfoAt(size_t n) const {
    return _myVector.at(n);
}

const_info_iterator getInfoBegin() const {
    return _myVector.begin();
}

const_info_iterator getInfoEnd() const {
    return _myVector.end();
}

size_t getInfoSize() const {
    return _myVector.size();
}

// plus anything else they need.
```

`const_info_iterator` is a typedef to a class that's slightly annoying to write. It has to wrap a `std::vector<someObj *>::const_iterator` and const-ify the type of `operator*`. `boost::transform_iterator` might be useful, or it's not all that bad to write from scratch. Bidirectional iterators do require the most operator overloads, though.

Now, if the caller really wants a vector of `const someObj*`, then using my interface they can easily get a snapshot at any particular moment:

```
std::vector<const someObj*> mycopy(myinfo.getInfoBegin(), myinfo.getInfoEnd());
```

What they can't have is a `vector` that continually reflects changes made to some other `vector` of a different type somewhere else -- `std::vector` just doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks, Steve, maybe your approach fits best to my needs. You're right, that since the user of my class will not be allowed to change the data structure I give him, why should I give the whole data structure ... just expose the elements of this structure using a set of accessors that will ease his life.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<T*>` and `std::vector<const T*>` are not same type. How can you write this:

```
std::vector<T*> obj(100);
std::vector<const T*> & ref = obj; //error
```

This is that you're doing in your code, which is invalid. You can make a reference of one type, to refer to object of other type.

So try this:

```
std::vector<const someObj*> getInfoVector() const
{
    return std::vector<const someObj*>(_myVector.begin(), _myVector.end());
}
```

Now that it's returning a *temporary* vector which contains the *pointers* from the original vector. Also, note that return type is **not** *reference* anymore.

Comment: Just curious, but why the `const` on the return value?  (Note too that returning a copy does not have the same semantics as returning a reference to the real thing.)

Comment: @James: Yeah. It's not needed.

Comment: The const on the pointers in the return value is, so that no one can change the values of the objects pointed by those pointers. Thanks Nawaz, what you say explains the situation, but if I return a copy of the vector, it will slow the program too much, so I cannot afford that (speed is crucial in my application).

Answer (score 0):

you could write getInfoVector like this:

```
std::vector<const someObj*> getInfoVector() const
{
  std::vector<const someObj*> obj;
  std::copy( _myVector.begin(), _myVector.end(), std::back_inserter( obj ) );
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Yep, this would work, but again, will have serious impact on the performance ... I don't want to give special new structure to the user of my vector, I just want to protect him from doing foolish things with it.

Answer (score 0):

> What would you do in this situation?

as an alternative to other answers, here is a simple approach which requires no copy or allocation:

```
const someObj* SomeInfo::getSomeObjAt(const size_t& idx) const {
  return this->_myVector.at(idx);
}
```

even better in many contexts, just have SomeInfo *not* expose its internals.

Comment: Thanks, Justin, this looks pretty much to the first answer -> "don't give access to your data structure, only to its elements"

Comment: presumably, you are referring to Steve Jessop's answer as the first: my answer was posted 2 minutes prior to his (his answer is by all means a more detailed description of my first point). my second point was also very important. in more detail, that means that `SomeInfo` should typically be the one to operate on its `somObj`s, rather than giving them to clients.